# Can this numpy.where() approach be adapted for two conditions instead of one?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing, multiple-conditions

I can get `numpy.where()` to work for one condition but not two conditions.

**For one condition:**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5])
i, = np.where(a < 2)
print(i)
>> [ 0  5  8 10 11 12] ## indices where a[i] = 1
```

**For two conditions:**

```
# condition = (a > 1 and a < 3)
# i, = np.where(condition)
i, = np.where(a > 1 and a < 3)
print(i)
>> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I read up on `a.any()` and `a.all()` [in this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820779/how-to-use-numpy-all-or-numpy-any/40821064#40821064), but this doesn't work for my purpose since I want all indices that fit the condition rather than a single boolean value.

Is there a way to adapt this for two conditions?

Comment: This value error is produced when you use a boolean array in a scalar context like an `if`, or in this case Python's `and`.  Use `&` instead.  And control operator order with `()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `np.where((a > 1) & (a < 3))`